# Menu Bar Time Disappeared

Tags: indicator, panel

Hello can anyone help me, my time on the menu bar has disappeared, one day I noticed it was gone, in system settings I do not have a time and date option either.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, please help

Comment: try `initctl restart indicator-datetime`,it will help restart the datetime indicator service.

Comment: @Momo mind turning this into an answer? This was the solution I ended up using and it worked fine. Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 37):

For me, this make the clock, time, date come back to menu bar: `killall unity-panel-service`

Comment: I have tried that in ubuntu 14.04 and it works too.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem while I was also dealing with another bug to do with my keyboard layout changing spontaneously, and the fix for that also brought back my time and date display.

Try the following command:

> sudo restart lightdm

Seemed to work for me, anyway. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this will restart your current X session so all of your running programs will be terminated.  You'll probably want to close everything you're working on before running this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the panel "indicator" for date and time back by running:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

That will restore the time readout on the top panel for you.

Answer (score 1):

As someone pointed out, I typed:

`initctl restart indicator-datetime`

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you repair the `Unity` and check if the issue is resolved. I had the same problem once and the following commands did the trick.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Answer (score 0):

It means your chosen region is not matched to your local server.

To correct:

1. set the time and date to your actual region (e.g. China)
2. use synaptic to select the repository server for your actual region (e.g. China).
3. reboot.

This should solve the issue. Recurrence may be caused by change in location, or change in server, or update/upgrade. If so, repeat the above.